# Pivot_longer in r for multiple columns with multiple values

Tags: r

I have very new to r. Much appreciated if anyone could help.

I have a data set as follows:

| name | q5_a | q5_b | q5_c | q5_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sam | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| tom | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| abby | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

so it's a multiple choice questions where people can choose more than one answers, and the column a, b, c, d is the answer of question 5. In the table, 1 representing that person has chosen the answers, 0 means not chosen.  How can I use pivot_longer in rstudio to make it like the following table?

| name | q5 |
| --- | --- |
| sam | a |
| sam | b |
| tom | b |
| tom | c |
| abby | a |

update:

I'm not sure how to present it here. The NA is the missing values, not the string as "na".

| name | q5_a | q5_b | q5_c | q5_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sam | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| tom | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| abby | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| jack | NA | NA | NA | NA |

so even though jack didn't answer the question, i still want here to be in the table. Something like the following table:

| name | q5 |
| --- | --- |
| sam | a |
| sam | b |
| tom | b |
| tom | c |
| abby | a |
| jack | NA |

Comment: use `pivot_longer(df1, cols = -name, names_to = 'q5') %>% filter(value ==1) %>% select(-value)`

Comment: Thanks so much. It really works. I got one more question. If there is a new person jack who didn't answer the question, so i have him as na in my data. I don't want him to be removed from my new table. How can i let him be in the new table an just shown as na.

Answer (score 0):

We can reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, `filter` the rows where 'value' is 1 and remove the 'value' column with `select`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df1, cols = -name, names_to = 'q5') %>%
    filter(value ==1|is.na(value)) %>% 
    select(-value)
```

---

Using the new data

```
df2 %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -name, names_to = c(".value", "q5a"), 
      names_sep = "_") %>% 
    filter(q5 ==1|is.na(q5)) %>% 
    group_by(name) %>%
    summarise(q5 = if(all(is.na(q5))) NA_character_ else q5a, .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  name  q5   
  <chr> <chr>
1 abby  a    
2 jack  <NA> 
3 sam   a    
4 sam   b    
5 tom   b    
6 tom   c
```

---

We could also do

```
library(stringr)
df2 %>% 
    mutate(across(-name, 
       ~ case_when(as.logical(.) ~str_remove(cur_column(), ".*_"), 
          !. ~ ""))) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols= -name, names_to = "name1", values_to = "q5") %>% 
    select(-name1) %>%
    distinct %>% 
    filter(nzchar(q5))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  name  q5   
  <chr> <chr>
1 sam   a    
2 sam   b    
3 tom   b    
4 tom   c    
5 abby  a    
6 jack  <NA>
```

#### data

```
df2 <-structure(list(name = c("sam", "tom", "abby", "jack"), q5_a = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, NA), q5_b = c(1L, 1L, 0L, NA), q5_c = c(0L, 1L, 0L, NA
), q5_d = c(0L, 0L, 0L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: If someone didn't answer this questions, it will shows as na in the data, so how to keep the na in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, i could use this to filter the 1 and na in column value, but in the column q5, it does not replace na there.

Comment: I've update the post. Sorry I'm very new to here. Not really sure how to give the data

Comment: @XiaoyuTian I updated the post with two solutions.  I hope you will find it useful